# React testing : React-leaflet is showing '_leaflet_id' is null when mock json is passed to GeoJson

Tags: reactjs, geojson, react-testing-library, react-leaflet

I am adding test cases for custom Map component which is created using react-leaflet. But when passing mock data to GeoJson for showing the clusters in map, it shows the error as "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_leaflet_id' in null".

Expecting test case should success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.